# Getting an error with no resources when creating a vm that is ongoing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I keep getting an error message that says there are not enough resources in the zone to create a VM (Us-Central F). This has been going on for a couple of days. Is there a way to fix this or report this? Any advice and answers would be appreciated!

Comment: **not enough resources** sounds like some resources are stuck. What are you trying to do? Show some code

Comment: Im just trying to create a vm for school and to compare it with Azure and the error i get this error: The zone 'projects/stable-hologram-276104/zones/us-central1-f' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.

Comment: Did you try a different zone? You might even have to try a different region depending on how popular the instance type is that you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can [reserve resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) you need or wait and try your luck with creating desired VM. Changing the machine type, amount of ram etc - lowering VM specs will also increase your chances.

Otherwise you have to use other zone or even region - there's no way around it since even GCP has limited resources and due to high demand some of them may not be available. The only difference will be higher latency.